# Could not find gnatmake binary after MacOS installation

Tags: macos, makefile, ada, gnat, ghdl

After installing [gnat for darwin (arm) macos](https://www.adacore.com/download/more), following [this guide](https://sites.radford.edu/%7Eitec320/2018fall-nokie/compileInstall.html) (see "AdaCore compiler on mac" section), I could not find the `gnatmake` in the `/bin` folder that all the other binaries were in. Quite confused. (I wanted to install `gnat` to build `ghdl`.)

Comment: The Adacore link provides access to x86_64 GNAT binaries that can be run using Rosetta. I've used Simon Wright's earlier gcc-12.1.0-aarch64 download to build GHDL 3.0.0-dev (2.0.0.r444.ga33efb91d) a year ago. Both have gnatmake and Apple Silicon binaries can be more that twice as fast (the mcode version providing JIT code generation currently only supports x86_64). See the [#Issue 1115 comment](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/issues/1115#issuecomment-1176963769), a brief synopsis of the effort.  An arm64 version isn't released, ghdl lacking access to a github build platform.

Comment: I forgot to specify you have to navigate to the correct binary from the link. There isn't an explicit link because it's in a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you’re running on a Mac with Apple silicon (e.g. M1, M2).

You can run Intel binaries on Apple silicon under Rosetta emulation (it’s very fast, don’t worry). The machine will ask you if that’s OK the first time, thereafter it’s transparent.

For Intel (x86_64) binaries, see [here](https://github.com/simonjwright/distributing-gcc/releases/tag/gcc-13.1.0-x86_64).

For Apple (aarch64, aka arm64) binaries, see [here](https://github.com/simonjwright/distributing-gcc/releases/tag/gcc-13.1.0-aarch64-2)

For the IDE, GNAT Studio, see [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuada/files/GNAT_GPL%20Mac%20OS%20X/2022-monterey/). There’s an issue: not all the menu choices respond to mouse clicks, you may have to use the cursor keys and [RET].

Comment: Thanks. I found another workaround, so I haven't tested it. I'm curious, if you downvoted this post (someone did), what was the reason? (would appreciate feedback for future posts)

Comment: SO was originally supposed to be about programming problems; people were supposed to post actual code showing what they’d tried, what the expected to happen, and what actually happened. Your Q clearly doesn’t match _that_ model. On the other hand, there are few enough Ada responders that _I_ try to answer questions like yours. Not that I wouldn’t downvote someone who obviously hadn’t made the least effort!